# input somente numeros com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação, input

tenho uma função que valida os caracteres digitados e nao deixa o usuario utilizar caracteres especiais mas esta mesma função nao funciona para numeros, alguem conhece alguma função em jquery para validar somente numeros no input

```
function sem_n(e,args)
{       
    if (document.all){var evt=event.keyCode;} 
    else{var evt = e.charCode;} 
    var valid_chars = '0123456789'+args;    // criando a lista de teclas permitidas
    var chr= String.fromCharCode(evt);  // pegando a tecla digitada
    if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 ){return true;} 
    if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 || evt < 9){return true;}   
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: quero impedir que o usuario digite qualquer coisa que nao seja numeros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('keypress', 'input.somente-numero', function(e) {
  var square = document.getElementById("sonumero");
    var key = (window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
 if((key > 47 && key < 58)) {
     sonumero.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
     return true;
     
   } else {
      sonumero.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
   return (key == 8 || key == 0)?true:false;
   
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>Somente números
<input type="text" 
       size="10" 
       id="sonumero"
       name="sonumero" 
       class="somente-numero" 
       value="" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```js
$('#numeric').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val(this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numeric">
```

Primeiro eu monitoro o `input` pelo evento `keyup`, quando um caractere é digitado eu pego o valor do campo e apago todos os caracteres não numéricos (`\D`)

Answer (score 2):

Olá, você pode colocar isso direto no input que resolve:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
```

espero ter ajudado!!

Answer (score 1):

> quero impedir que o usuario digite qualquer coisa que nao seja numeros

Use o próprio `input` do tipo `number` do `HTML`

O `<input type="number">` define um campo de entrada numérico .

Você também pode definir restrições sobre quais números são aceitos.

O exemplo a seguir exibe um campo de entrada numérico, onde você pode inserir um valor de 1 a 5:

```
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    </form>
```

**Restrições de Entrada**

Aqui está uma lista de algumas restrições de entrada comuns (algumas são novas no HTML5):

*disabled* - Especifica que um campo de entrada deve ser desabilitado

*max* * - Especifica o valor máximo para um campo de entrada

*maxlength* - Especifica o número máximo de caracteres para um campo de entrada

*min* * - Especifica o valor mínimo para um campo de entrada

*pattern* * - Especifica uma expressão regular para verificar o valor de entrada

*readonly* - Especifica que um campo de entrada é somente leitura (não pode ser alterado)

*required* * - Especifica que um campo de entrada é obrigatório (deve ser preenchido)

*size* - Especifica a largura (em caracteres) de um campo de entrada

*step* * - Especifica os intervalos de número legais para um campo de entrada

*value* - Especifica o valor padrão para um campo de entrada

```
* = HTML5
```

Isso pode ser visto em: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Esses `inputs` atualmente vem com um `spin button` para aumentar e reduzir o valor, caso queira desabilitar os mesmos, poderá fazer com `CSS`:

```
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    input[type=number] {
        -moz-appearance:textfield;
    }
```

Comment: eu tente isso mas por algum motivo nao deu certo, so utilizo html5 mas sua resposta foi extremamente eficiente

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#cpf').bind('keyup', function(e){
           if(e.keyCode < 47 || e.keyCode >57 ){
               alert(" esse e um campo apenas numerico");
               $(this).val("");
           }
       })
```