# Como remover os botões do Input type="number"

Tags: html, css

Como remover os dois botões do Input type="number" no HTML5?
Exemplo:

```html
<p>Quero que isso:</p>
<input type="number">

<p>Vire isso porém sem usar o text, pois preciso do comportamento do number:</p>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Veja a resposta de nosso amigo leo, acredito o que você precisa é um input aceitando apenas números. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187172/input-somente-numeros-com-jquery

Comment: Possível duplicata de [input somente numeros com jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187172/input-somente-numeros-com-jquery)

Comment: Duplicata não é, se eu preciso usar type= "number" e não "text" não é duplicata, mas eu vou ler a pergunta sim, talvez a utilize. Obrigado

Comment: A duplicata não é definida pela pergunta mas sim pela resposta. Eu acredito que a resposta de nosso amigo Leo irá suprir sua necessidade.

Comment: Ok, resolvendo o problema , está tudo certo :D é que eu não queria utilizar js, mas tudo bem, irei aplicar.

Comment: Se você tiver um certo conhecimento em inglês você pode dar uma olhada nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999067/how-to-force-only-numbers-in-a-input-without-javascript , veja a resposta

Comment: @Bsalvo Pelo que eu entendi não é bom utilizar do type para formatação/mascara, eu vou fazer pelo JS mesmo como na pergunta que foi sinalizada.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bloqueando por css.

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

Ou poderia fazer um text e validar aceitando apenas números. Conforme abaixo:

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</input>
```

Comment: Mas ai tem limitação, não posso apagar o numero.

Comment: Tenho outra solução vou postar.Vê se resolve?

Comment: Nossa, aqui não resolveu será que é porque estou no Firefox? Continua com os dois botões

Comment: Então css tem sempre limitações ... vou checkar no meu firefox uso vivaldi e funciona, tb testei no chrome e funciona.

Comment: Aqui no meu funciona corretamente. Acontece que para validações é sempre bom utilizarmos uma LP que irá cumprir seu ofício em qualquer navegador. Entretanto a utilidade da resposta é significativa!

Comment: Adicionei essa css  -moz-appearance:textfield; testa ai vê se resolve.

Comment: Agora funcionou, 100%, e resolveu meu problema, apesar de que eu vou utilizar JS também.

Comment: Show leo, muito bom abraços...

Comment: Funcionou. Muito bom!